# How to refresh the database queries in Shiny?

Tags: mysql, r, database, shiny

I'm building a dashboard in `Shiny` app, but getting some troubles for refreshing/updating the MySQL database connected in `Rstudio`.

I read about `reactivePoll()` but not sure how to implemented on my queries, can someone please help me?

```
db <- dbConnect(
  RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "database",
  host = "...",
  username = "user",
  password = "password"
  

)  





pool::poolClose(db)
 
 
###QUERIES


autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(10000,session = NULL)

data_query <- reactive({
  autoInvalidate()
dbGetQuery(db, "select * from database where date = curdate()")
colnames(data_query()) <- c("table","name","currency", "status", "time")
data_query_dt <- as.data.table(data_query_order())



})



data_query_2 <- reactive({
  autoInvalidate()
  dbGetQuery(db, "select * from database2  where DATE(last_update)=curdate()")
colnames(data_query_2()) <- c("name2","id", "id1")
data_query_2_dt <- as.data.table(data_query_2())

})
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including data and your code which can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Have a look at https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5 and [mre]

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your reply. I think I found the good solution now for the issue, with `reactivePoll()` in the server. I will be testing the code to uodate my question with the one works for me.